# Live wallpaper Shortcut activity with out appearing in launcher list

Tags: android, android-intent

Hope this will be Useful for someone making Live wallpapers.

What i need?

1) A shortcut with activity that brings live wallpaper settings or Live wallpaper menu
2) Shortcut should not appear in the launcher list or application menu
3) Shortcut may or may not come in homescreen (depends on "Auto-add widgets" option in google play"
4) Activity should run from the Market using the Open button after installation

What most people use is the below code

```
<activity android:name="com.package.test.MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: I need that open button enabled like in that picture and no shortcut on the application menu of device. ( Homescreen shortcut may or may not displayed on homescreen)

Answer (score 1):

Use `<category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />` instead of `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

Now the shortcut wont appear in launcher menu or Application menu , but still u can open it from market link directly.Thanks